# Html form rewrites by?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've an HTML form that is being rewritten by something. So i can't get some of the fields from $_POST. It's run by PHP 5.3 and WordPress.

Here is the original code :

```
<input type="text" name="edituserid" value="25">                                         
<input type="text" name="editpostid" value="940">                                        
<input type="text" name="save" value="save">
```

And it's transformed into this :

```
<input type="text" name="oyrjwmgf" value="25">
<input type="text" name="qktghnbr" value="1101">
<input type="text" name="sdzddzss" value="save">
```

I've other field that are not impacted and stay untouched.

I've never seen that before....

I've tried:

- changing PHP version
- changing name of the field
- adding more fields

When I `var_dump`, I got some strange variables:

```
  ["xsyyblcxl"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["eyzyho"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["hjklfsoyu"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["qmczoemn"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

… just get my variables in $_POST ... sorry for my bad english =)

Comment: With the information you have provided, I'm not sure how we would be expected to identify the logic that is manipulating your fields.

Comment: If you "View Source" of the page, **not Inspect Element**, are the form names correct?

Comment: You are right, when i see the source, the html is OK.

Comment: Then that means the server is serving the page up with the correct names.  So the randomization of the names is happening on the client, with some script or some browser plugin.

Comment: Yes. let me check what javascript or jQuery is loaded ...

Comment: I've unlocked the url, here is the link ...https://www.ophtalink.com/editer-une-offre-admin/?editid=1101&userid=1

Comment: Don't ask people to debug your website.  That is off topic for StackOverflow.  If you cannot identify the problem, you need to debug it yourself.

Comment: Sure !! Thak you for your help !!! :D

Comment: I will share the answer here, just in case someone got the same problem.

Comment: Found ! It was the plugin Gravity Form who rewrite fields. thank you for your help !

Comment: Glad you were able to identify your issue.

Comment: yup that because fo you =) ive spend 2 hours on this ... it was simple .. =)

Comment: It always is, in *retrospect*. :D

Comment: I guess you have one plugin which rewriting your fields. Try to disable all plugins, and reactive them one by one. And trying on the same time if it works.

Comment: **Danger** PHP 5.3 hasn't had a security update in 4 years, 9 months! Upgrade to a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Php version is 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange beheviour. Just renaming a jquery script and queuing again in WordPress and it work.

I don't understand but it worked